# Dynamics CRM error with plugin tutorial

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to write my first plugin using this tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695782.aspx

However, when registered I get this error when saving a contact.

```xml
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): Plugin: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client, Version=5.0.9689.2166, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.Detail: 
 <OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts"> 
 <ErrorCode>-2147220956</ErrorCode> 
 <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" /> 
 <Message>Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): Plugin: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client, Version=5.0.9689.2166, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</Message> 
 <Timestamp>2013-06-03T19:23:50.6212306Z</Timestamp> 
 <InnerFault i:nil="true" /> 
 <TraceText> 

 [PluginWalkthrough: Plugin] 
 [b40b42a2-82cc-e211-8bf1-984be16dae4d: Plugin: Create of contact] 


 </TraceText> 
 </OrganizationServiceFault>
```

As I am using CRM Online the Microsoft.Xrm.Client assembly is supposed to be in the GAC allready. I am stuck here, please help me out, what I am doing wrong???

Here's the code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Xrm;

public class Plugin : IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        Entity entity;

        // Check if the input parameters property bag contains a target
        // of the create operation and that target is of type Entity.
        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            // Obtain the target business entity from the input parameters.
            entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            // Verify that the entity represents a contact.
            if (entity.LogicalName != "contact") { return; }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

            var id = (Guid)context.OutputParameters["id"];

            AddNoteToContact(service, id);
        }
        catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(
            "An error occurred in the plug-in.", ex);
        }
    }

    private static void AddNoteToContact(IOrganizationService service, Guid id)
    {
        using (var crm = new XrmServiceContext(service))
        {

            var contact = crm.ContactSet.Where(c => c.ContactId == id).First();
            Debug.Write(contact.FirstName);

            var note = new Annotation
            {
                Subject = "Created with plugin",
                NoteText = "This Note was created by the example plug-in",
                ObjectId = contact.ToEntityReference(),
                ObjectTypeCode = contact.LogicalName
            };

            crm.AddObject(note);
            crm.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's a screenshot of my references:

[image: Screenshot of References]

Comment: is very strange that you still have these issues, can you post your code (also with the using) and a screenshot with the references in your project?

Comment: It is very uncommon to even need Microsoft.Xrm.Client in a plugin. What happens when you remove the reference?

Comment: I just tested a plugin with your code and your reference and it works. I suggest to open a new trial crm online, generate the Xrm.cs against this new environment, build and register the plugin. At this point we can't exclude that there is something wrong with your crm online instance.

Comment: When I removed the ref it generated errors in the Xrm.cs. Removing the Xrm.cs the XrmServiceContext and Annotation classes in the code are not fount anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help! Fixed it by regenerating the Xrm.cs Still not sure what is different with this Xrm.cs but it works. Regenerated using this command:

> crmsvcutil.exe /out:Xrm\Xrm.cs
>   /url:https://mydomain.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc
>   /username:martijn@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com /password:itssecret
>   /namespace:Xrm /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext

Comment: Once again. Thanks for all the help Guido!!