# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have created a plug-in in `CRM.` It’s registered successfully. Inside my plug-in I have created a web service with many functions.
After successful calling of plug-in step I am getting error-

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client, Version=5.0.9689.2166, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies`. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   To solve this issue I have created the New XRM.cs file from crmsvcutil.exe but got the same issue. Searched more about this but no solutions found yet.

**NOTE**: I am using the Microsoft hosted version of CRM

Here below the reference files which I am using.

- microsoft.crm.sdk.proxy
- Microsoft.CSharp
- **microsoft.xrm.client**
- microsoft.xrm.portal
- **microsoft.xrm.sdk**
- System
- System System.Core
- System.Data
- System.Data.Services
- System.Data.Services.Client
- System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
- System.Runtime.Serialization
- System.ServiceModel
- System.Xml
- System.Xml.Linq

Is there any way to run my plugin on Hosted version of CRM???

Appreciate if any help :)

Comment: Have you seen this: http://vincenttechnotes.blogspot.com/2011/12/crm-online-cant-find.html

Comment: Its not working. I already created the new XRM.cs file.. inside my plugin see the code ` var connection = CrmConnection.Parse("ServiceUri=myconnectiondetails");
                        var service = new OrganizationService(connection);
                        var context1 = new CrmOrganizationServiceContext(connection);

                        var xrm = new XrmServiceContext(context1);`. the xrm object raise this issue.

Comment: I reckon David's answer could be on the money. Also check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16928710/685760) that describes something similar.

Comment: Can we use like this `IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
                        IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);                        

                        var xrm = new XrmServiceContext(service); `

Comment: What's the version number of the SDK libraries>

Comment: Please post your plugin code. The services may be being consumed incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft.XRM.Client is <strike>usually</strike> not needed by the plug-in.
It is needed to connect to CRM from an outside application.
 **Microsoft.XRM.Client has been removed from the SDK since CRM 2016**.

Plugins do not automatically resolve dependencies in your project, they have to already be on the server.


<strike>Microsoft.XRM.Client can be placed in the GAC if it is needed by the plugin.</strike>

**Update for Dynamics CRM 2015**
The NuGet package [Microsoft.CrmSdk.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.Extensions/) contains Microsoft.Xrm.Client.

**Update for Dynamics CRM 2016 and Dynamics 365**
Microsoft.Xrm.Client is no longer part of the SDK.
The NuGet package [Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies/) contains everything needed for plugin development.

The various parts of the [Dynamics CRM SDK are in NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/crmsdk).
NuGet is a much better solution than adding Dynamics CRM dlls as project references; especially for source control and team development.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, How to place Microsoft.XRM.Client.dll on Online CRM in the GAC?

Comment: I have created the xrm.cs file removing parameters and it works, no need of xrm.client. [link](http://dynamicslollipops.blogspot.in/2011/07/mscrm-2011-early-binding-plugin.html). But I'm facing issue with OptionSetValue. how to set these values. [link](http://kelvinshen.blogspot.co.il/2012/01/generate-code-with-crmsvcutilexe.html)

Comment: There is no access to the GAC in CRM Online. You can only place assemblies in the GAC if you have access to the CRM server.

Comment: Please ask another question for the option set values; if I answered your question please mark it as the answer.

Comment: The OP was very clear in the original question that they were using the "Microsoft hosted version of CRM". -- The advice to put the dll into the GAC is very unhelpful in this situation.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this issue by using this command.

```
CrmSvcUtil.exe /out:"Xrm.cs" 
               /url:http://crm/Contoso/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc 
               /namespace:Xrm 
               /servicecontextname:XrmServiceContext
               /servicecontextprefix:Xrm
```

removing code customization options solved my issue.

```
/codeCustomization:"Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration.CodeCustomization, Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration"
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft.Xrm.Client.dll doesn't actually appear to work if running from the GAC. This is because of some dodgy type resolution methods it has that only work if the assembly is loaded locally. I have raised an issue with full details about that here: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/144464.aspx