# Dynamic CRM online 2015 custom workflow early bound error

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I create a XRM.cs file from crmsvcutil.exe and refer to the url

[Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223890/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-xrm-client)

So I merge 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client' with my workflow assembly and register it in database at CRM online server.Then I got this error:

```
System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.UIPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.KnownProxyTypesProvider.LoadKnownTypes(Assembly assembly)
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.KnownProxyTypesProvider.RegisterAssembly(Assembly assembly)
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AssemblyBasedKnownProxyTypesProvider.GetNameForType(Type type)
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.CheckEntitySubclass(Type entityType)
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.CreateQuery[TEntity]()
at Xrm.XrmServiceContext.get_AccountSet()
at Mailer.SendMailDaily.Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
The action that failed was:
InheritanceDemand
The type of the first permission that failed was:
System.Security.Permissions.UIPermission
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
MyComputer
```

Here is my code, Can anybody solve this?

```
IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.InitiatingUserId);
var xrm = new XrmServiceContext(service);
var customers = from c in xrm.AccountSet select c;
```

Answer (score 0):

To be clear you mean this Microsoft assembly?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.client.aspx

Why did you do that?

Just register your own plugin assembly.

Comment: I create a XRM.cs file from crmsvcutil.exe and refer to the url

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223890/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-xrm-client

Comment: That doesnt really explain why you are merging. Why exactly are you doing in the merge?

Comment: I merge it to resovle "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client" error.

Comment: I just don't think you need to merge that. Typically you don't need that assembly inside a plugin. Try removing all references from your project.

Comment: reomve the "Microsoft.Xrm.Client" reference I will get an error in "the public partial class XrmServiceContext : Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmOrganizationServiceContext"  in Xrm.cs.